# SQL Server : compare rows, exclude from results when some values are the same

Tags: sql, compare, rows

I have the following SQL Server query problem.

If there is a row where Issue_DATE = as Maturity_Date in another row, and if both rows have the same ID and Amount USD, then none of these rows should be displayed.

Here is a simplified version of my table:

```
ID      ISSUE_DATE                  MATURITY_DATE            AMOUNT_USD
1       2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     2015-12-01 00:00:00.000      5000
1       2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     2001-09-19 00:00:00.000       700
2       2014-04-09 00:00:00.000     2019-04-09 00:00:00.000       400
1       2015-12-01 00:00:00.000     2016-12-31 00:00:00.000      5000
5       2015-02-24 00:00:00.000     2015-02-24 00:00:00.000      8000
4       2012-11-29 00:00:00.000     2015-11-29 00:00:00.000     10000
3       2015-01-21 00:00:00.000     2018-01-21 00:00:00.000     17500
2       2015-02-02 00:00:00.000     2015-12-05 00:00:00.000     12000
1       2015-01-12 00:00:00.000     2018-01-12 00:00:00.000     18000
2       2015-12-05 00:00:00.000     2016-01-10 00:00:00.000     12000
```

Result should be:

```
ID      ISSUE_DATE                  MATURITY_DATE           AMOUNT_USD
1       2010-01-01 00:00:00.000     2001-09-19 00:00:00.000       700
2       2014-04-09 00:00:00.000     2019-04-09 00:00:00.000       400
5       2015-02-24 00:00:00.000     2015-02-24 00:00:00.000      8000
4       2012-11-29 00:00:00.000     2015-11-29 00:00:00.000     10000
3       2015-01-21 00:00:00.000     2018-01-21 00:00:00.000     17500
1       2015-01-12 00:00:00.000     2018-01-12 00:00:00.000     18000
```

I tried with self join, but I do not get right result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this? 'not exists' is the way of doing it.

```
select * from table t1 where not exists (select 'x' from table t2 where t1.issue_date = t2.maturity_date and t1.amount_usd=t2.amount_usd and t1.id = t2.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think about making subquery of all the dupes and then eliminating them from the first table like so:

```
select t1.ID
, t1.ISSUE_DATE
, t1.MATURITY_DATE
, t1.AMOUNT_USD  
 FROM
    t1 
LEFT JOIN
(select a.ID
    , a.ISSUE_DATE
    , a.MATURITY_DATE
    , a.AMOUNT_USD
FROM
    t1 a
INNER JOIN
    ti b
) dupes
   on
t1.ID = dupes.ID
   WHERE dupes.ID IS NULL;
```